# Can I upload an object in memory to FTP using Python?

Tags: python, object, ftp, upload, ftplib

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
mysock = urllib.urlopen('http://localhost/image.jpg')
fileToSave = mysock.read()
oFile = open(r"C:\image.jpg",'wb')
oFile.write(fileToSave)
oFile.close
f=file('image.jpg','rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+os.path.basename('image.jpg'),f)
os.remove('image.jpg')
```

Writing files to disk and then imediately deleting them seems like extra work on the system that should be avoided.  Can I upload an object in memory to FTP using Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), the file object (`f` in your code) only needs to support the `.read(blocksize)` call to work with `storbinary`. When faced with questions like this, I go to the source, in this case lib/python2.6/ftplib.py:

```
def storbinary(self, cmd, fp, blocksize=8192, callback=None):
    """Store a file in binary mode.  A new port is created for you.

    Args:
      cmd: A STOR command.
      fp: A file-like object with a read(num_bytes) method.
      blocksize: The maximum data size to read from fp and send over
                 the connection at once.  [default: 8192]
      callback: An optional single parameter callable that is called on
                on each block of data after it is sent.  [default: None]

    Returns:
      The response code.
    """
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
    while 1:
        buf = fp.read(blocksize)
        if not buf: break
        conn.sendall(buf)
        if callback: callback(buf)
    conn.close()
    return self.voidresp()
```

As commented, it only wants a [file-like object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), indeed it not even be particularly file-like, it just needs `read(n)`. [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) provides such "memory file" services.

Comment: Great answer.  I figured this should work, but couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: ftplib doesn't allow you to send StringIO you have to pass BytesIO

Answer (score 2):

You can use any in-memory [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), like [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
from io import BytesIO
```

It works both in binary mode with [`FTP.storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary):

```
f = BytesIO(b"the contents")
ftp.storbinary("STOR /path/file.txt", f)
```

as well as in ascii/text mode with [`FTP.storlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storlines):

```
f = BytesIO(b"the contents")
ftp.storlines("STOR /path/file.txt", f)
```

---

For more advanced examples, see:

- [Python - Upload a in-memory file (generated by API calls) in FTP by chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51632215/850848)
- [Python - Transfer a file from HTTP(S) URL to FTP/Dropbox without disk writing (chunked upload)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53544969/850848)
- [How to send CSV file directly to an FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54783483/850848)

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP(...)
f = urllib.urlopen('http://localhost/image.jpg')
ftp.storbinary('STOR image.jpg', f)
```