# Nothing In My Text File After Uploaded With FTP

Tags: python, ftp

At the moment the users inputs are saved as a file on the computer, I think want it to also be uploaded to my ftp server, I have got it working sort of, but there is nothing in the file, there is likely to be an easy error as I am new to programming, thanks

```
quotation = input("Do you want to save a quotation? ")

if (quotation == "yes") :
    quotationName = input("What do you want to save the quotation as? ")

    text_file = open("{}.txt".format(quotationName),"w") #(w) opens files in write
    text_file.write ("The total lawn area is {}\n".format(totalAreaLawn))
    text_file.write ("The total for the lawn is £{}\n\n".format(totalCostLawn))
    text_file.write ("The total concrete area is {}\n".format(totalAreaConcrete))
    text_file.write ("The total for the concrete is £{}\n\n".format(totalCostConcrete))
    text_file.write ("The total wooden deck area is {}\n".format(totalAreaWoodenDeck))
    text_file.write ("The total for the wooden deck is £{}\n\n".format(totalCostWoodenDeck))
    text_file.write ("The total rectangular pond area is {}\n".format(totalAreaRectangularPond))
    text_file.write ("The total for the wooden deck is £{}\n\n".format(totalCostRectangularPond))
    text_file.write ("The total number of water features needed is {}\n".format(numberOfWaterFeatures))
    text_file.write ("The total for the water features is £{}\n\n".format(totalCostWaterFeatures))
    text_file.write ("The total number of garden lights needed is {}\n".format(numberOfGardenLights))
    text_file.write ("The total for the garden lights is £{}\n\n".format(totalCostGardenLighting))   

    #text_file.close()

    ftpconnect = ftplib.FTP('landscapegardening.freeiz.com','a6011438','L0g1tecH')

    saveDirectory = '/public_html/Quote'

    ftpconnect.cwd(saveDirectory)

    fileSend = open("{}.txt".format(quotationName),'rb')
    ftpconnect.storbinary('STOR {}.txt'.format(quotationName), fileSend)

    fileSend.close()
    ftpconnect.quit()      

    print("Quotation saved")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you commented out the line `text_file.close()`? With your code like this, there is no guarantee that anything is written to the file at the point you want to send it. I think the best way would be to close the file first (just comment in the close() line again) or if you do not want to reopen the same file to call text_file.flush() followed by [os.fsync(text_file)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync). If you opt for the second option remember to change `ftpconnect.storbinary('STOR {}.txt'.format(quotationName), fileSend)` to `ftpconnect.storbinary('STOR {}.txt'.format(quotationName), text_file)`. You also would have to change the open mode to 'r+' and to go to the beginning of the file using `text_file.seek(0)`.

Edit: Just saw that you actually only need a file-like object, see here for details:
[Can I upload an object in memory to FTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671118/can-i-upload-an-object-in-memory-to-ftp-using-python)

Comment: Commented it out as I was trying to test ways to get it to work, just uncommented it and it works great, thanks! :)