# how can i create a csv file directly to ftp server using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, ftp

am having a code to create a csv file and can upload it to ftp server

```
with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns1) #csv_columns1 is a list of value to become  as heading
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in vals['details']:# values for the header
        writer.writerow(data)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns2)#csv_columns1 is a list of value to become  as heading
    writer.writeheader()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)#csv_columns1 is a list of value to become  as heading
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in vals['OrderLine']:# values for the header
        writer.writerow(data)
        print(os.system('pwd'))

     Output_Directory = "ftp_path_to_store_file"
     username = "ftp_user_names"
     password = "ftp_password"
     ftp_ip = "ftp_host_ip"
     a1 = 'STOR %s.csv' % (order.name)

     try:
        ftp = FTP(ftp_ip)
        ftp.login(username, password)
        ftp.cwd(Output_Directory)
        with open(csv_file, "rb") as f:
             ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(csv_file), f)
```

but what i need was without creating a file on my computer i want to create a file directly to ftp server

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't write it to a file... write it to a `io.BytesIO` object... and then give `ftp.storbinary` that object...

Comment: i tried it too. but it shows me some error like writer object has no attribute  DictWriter. can you please show me how can i do that. with the above code

csv_column1=[head1, head2,head3]
csv_column2=[head21, head22,head23] ..etc

Comment: Why are you creating multiple CSV writers btw?

Comment: am having multiple lines of  heading to add to csv is there any other way to do that

Comment: That's not how CSV files work... but anyway... your code might just work by changing `with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:` to `with io.BytesIO() as csvfile`...

Comment: the how can replace this line              ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(csv_file), f)
in this os.path.basename

Comment: It shouldn't need replacing... You might need to do a `f.seek(0)` before the storbinary command but apart from that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the csv writer write to a `io.StringIO` object instead and then convert the output to an `io.BytesIO` object after encoding its text value to bytes:

```
import io
csvfile = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns1) #csv_columns1 is a list of value to become  as heading
writer.writeheader()
for data in vals['details']:# values for the header
    writer.writerow(data)
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns2)#csv_columns1 is a list of value to become  as heading
writer.writeheader()
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)#csv_columns1 is a list of value to become  as heading
writer.writeheader()
for data in vals['OrderLine']:# values for the header
    writer.writerow(data)
    print(os.system('pwd'))

Output_Directory = "ftp_path_to_store_file"
username = "ftp_user_names"
password = "ftp_password"
ftp_ip = "ftp_host_ip"
a1 = 'STOR %s.csv' % (order.name)

try:
    ftp = FTP(ftp_ip)
    ftp.login(username, password)
    ftp.cwd(Output_Directory)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(csv_file), io.BytesIO(csvfile.getvalue().encode()))
```

Comment: +1 - Though, while this works, it can be pretty inefficient, if the file becomes large. For more efficient (while more complicated) solution, see [Python - Upload a in-memory file (generated by API calls) in FTP by chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51632215/850848).