# Python - Transfer a file from HTTP(S) URL to FTP/Dropbox without disk writing (chunked upload)

Tags: python, ftp, python-requests, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a large file (500 Mb-1Gb) stored on a HTTP(S) location
(say `https://example.com/largefile.zip`).

I have read/write access to an FTP server

I have normal user permissions (no sudo).

Within these constraints I want to read the file from the HTTP URL via requests and send it to the FTP server without writing to disk first.

So normally, I would do.

```
response=requests.get('https://example.com/largefile.zip', stream=True)
with open("largefile_local.zip", "wb") as handle:                                                                                                     
 for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
  handle.write(data)
```

and then upload the local file to FTP. But I want to avoid the disk I/O. I cannot mount the FTP as a fuse filesystem because I don't have super user rights.

Ideally I would do something like `ftp_file.write()` instead of `handle.write()`. Is that possible? The ftplib documentation seems to assume only local files will be uploaded, not `response.content`. So ideally I would like to do

```
response=requests.get('https://example.com/largefile.zip', stream=True)
for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
 ftp_send_chunk(data)
```

I am not sure how to write `ftp_send_chunk()`.

There is a similar question here ([Python - Upload a in-memory file (generated by API calls) in FTP by chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632215/python-upload-a-in-memory-file-generated-by-api-calls-in-ftp-by-chunks)). My use case requires retrieving  a chunk from the HTTP URL and writing it to FTP.

P.S.: The solution provided in the answer (wrapper around urllib.urlopen) will work with dropbox uploads as well. I had problems working with my ftp provider ,so finally used dropbox, which is working reliably.

Note that Dropbox has a "add web upload" feature in the api which does the same thing (remote upload). That only works with "direct" links. In my use case the http_url came from a streaming service that was i.p. restricted. So this workaround became necessary.
Here's the code

```
import dropbox;
d = dropbox.Dropbox(<ACTION-TOKEN>);
f=FileWithProgress(filehandle);
filesize=filehandle.length;
targetfile='/'+fname;
CHUNK_SIZE=4*1024*1024
upload_session_start_result = d.files_upload_session_start(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE));
num_chunks=1
cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id,
                                           offset=CHUNK_SIZE*num_chunks)
commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=targetfile)
while CHUNK_SIZE*num_chunks < filesize:
 if ((filesize - (CHUNK_SIZE*num_chunks)) <= CHUNK_SIZE):
  print d.files_upload_session_finish(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),cursor,commit)
 else:
  d.files_upload_session_append(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),cursor.session_id,cursor.offset)
 num_chunks+=1
cursor.offset = CHUNK_SIZE*num_chunks
link = d.sharing_create_shared_link(targetfile)  
url = link.url
dl_url = re.sub(r"\?dl\=0", "?dl=1", url)
dl_url = dl_url.strip()
print 'dropbox_url: ',dl_url;
```

I think it should even be possible to do this with google-drive via their python api , but using credentials with their python wrapper is too hard for me. Check this[1](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload) and this[2](https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaInMemoryUpload-class.html)

Comment: Do you have shell access to `https://example.com/largefile.zip`? If so, why don't you upload `largefile.zip`  directly to the ftp server using `lftp` or similiar app?

Comment: Nope. I can only read the data from the url (its a cloud streaming service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy with [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen), as it returns a file-like object, which you can use directly with [`FTP.storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary).

```
ftp = FTP(host, user, passwd)

filehandle = urllib.request.urlopen(http_url)

ftp.storbinary("STOR /ftp/path/file.dat", filehandle)
```

---

If you want to monitor progress, implement a wrapper file-like object that will delegate calls to `filehandle` object, but will also display the progress:

```
class FileWithProgress:

    def __init__(self, filehandle):
        self.filehandle = filehandle
        self.p = 0

    def read(self, blocksize):
        r = self.filehandle.read(blocksize)
        self.p += len(r)
        print(str(self.p) + " of " + str(self.p + self.filehandle.length)) 
        return r

filehandle = urllib.request.urlopen(http_url)

ftp.storbinary("STOR /ftp/path/file.dat", FileWithProgress(filehandle))
```

---

For Python 2 use:

- `urllib.urlopen`, instead of `urllib.request.urlopen`.
- `filehandle.info().getheader('Content-Length')` instead of `str(self.p + filehandle.length)`

Comment: `urllib.request.urlopen` in Python 3, `urllib.urlopen` in Python 2, as my answer says.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer . I  tested this and this worked perfectly when the url was "direct". In case of redirection this gives a dummy file (1 Kb) which I think is the first level of redirection . In that case one can do urllib.urlopen(requests.open(http_url,stream=True).url).

Comment: Btw, I do not have any problem with redirects. `urlopen` redirects automatically for me.